# Multiple controllers use one xib

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder, xib

tried searching for something similar on the net but no luck. I have many different view controllers, but everyone of them have a tableview in it. So my question is:
Can i have one xib file with a tableview, that would be used by all of these controllers? If yes an example of how to do it would be super! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You can instantiate the xib's top level objects with:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourNibNameHere" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil]
```

This will get you all the objects (topmost views and/or gesture recognizers, etc) from that xib, then you find the one that you need (or if there's just one, it'll be the only one) and add it as a subview.

```
UIView *view = [topLevelObjects lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but what I would really like is something like this: I have a base class which has a tableview, and then do something like 
FirstViewController *c = [FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"baseNibName" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *sc = [SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"baseNibName" bundle:nil];

is this possible?

Comment: You could have Xib with whatever views you like in it, but in each of the ViewController whenever you create the view controller's view, you can use the code that I've provided to load that xib's view.